# Issue since upgraded from 4.0.3 to 5.0.1

Tags: performance, tcpdf, php-7, php-5.6, html2pdf

I upgraded from html2pdf 4.0.3 to latest 5.* some days ago. On a Debian standard server (PHP 5.6...), In order to prepare the Debian upgrade (from Jessie to Stretch, I'm a bit late). I think I read somewhere that I had to upgrade html2pdf to 5 to get it running on PHP 7. In any case, it surely is a good thing to upgrade this tool along with the distro.

I encountered a big performance problem I didn't have before.

Mainly, my PDF is a [sometimes] big table (many rows, a few columns) with basic stuff in it (amount, date, reference...)
With html2pdf 5, I need 1.5-2 seconds to generate that table (1 page) for only ~70 lines. Time increases exponentially with the number of lines (the server is a big one with, no performance problem, tuning/monitoring it myself blah blah blah).

- Approx. 40 seconds for 194 lines.
- Timeout after 10 minutes for ~1000 lines.
  Before that, for approx. 3000 lines, I needed a few seconds (maybe 5 or 10, I don't remember, but it was reasonnable).

I started to debug this and reduced a copy of my code to just this table with no PHP/MySQL processing, I just copied/pasted my table content. I activated setDebugMode to check.

Maybe I missed something simple (or my HTML code is dirty?), But I can't find why. I tried to remove every style attribute, it's a bit faster, but still slow, and exponentially slower.
If anyone has any idea, I'd appreciate.

Here you can find an example with only this table content (+ a footer) with the style attributes (I put it on all TD which is maybe a bad idea. And the same without any style nowhere.

[examples.zip](https://github.com/spipu/html2pdf/files/1315494/examples.zip)

You can copy/paste some TR/TD to generate hundreds of lines and check the processing time.

Comment: OK I modified "exemple07a.php" in /examples/res/, to increase the number of lines. Same thing => time becomes cray. I tried to add tables (with one line) instead of one table with many rows, same crazy processing time.

Comment: OK I switched back to v4.03 and won't change it unless I'm forced to.
I tested html2pdf 4.03 with PHP7, it's working.
With the 4.03, I can create a table with 500 lines in approx 13 seconds.
I can create 10 tables, each containing 500 lines, in approx 3 minutes, provided you increase the php time limit + memory to 512MB.
And with PHP7, it just took 13 seconds.
Now I just hope the 4.03 will still work for a long time...